# Why when I import a svg icon, only the pathname string is rendered, and not the actual svg icon?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a folder called `icons` inside `assets` folder, and inside `icons`, I have folders for different sizes, inside each one, I have a bunch of `svg` files, each containing a `svg` icon.

I created an `index.js` file inside icons folder, and then from it, I imported a `svg` file, and then export it, but when I import it from another component, all I get is a string pathname, and not the actual `svg`.

[Here's my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dwKW.png)

[Here's inside each size folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1re9.png)

[Here's inside the index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7e3h.png)

The `console.log` shows this:
`static/media/assets/icons/12x12/arrow-down-12.svg`

Note that, I also tried using `require` to import the `svg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to render the svg you need to pass it as a dynamic value to an image tag like this:

```
<img src={arrowDown12} alt="" >
```

Comment: I don't want to pass it to an img.